# NHibernate: Oracle & PostgreSql

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an application that stores data in database (oracle)
I have simple model

```
public class FileTemplate
{
    public string Xml { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and class map

```
public class FileTemplateMap : ClassMap<FileTemplate>
{
    public FileTemplateMap()
    {
        Table("FILE_TEMPLATE");
        Map(f => f.Xml, "XML").CustomSqlType("NCLOB");
        ...
    }
}
```

A want to add PostgreSql support. But PostgreSql doesn't have NCLOB data type. I modify my mapping:

```
    public class FileTemplateMap : ClassMap<FileTemplate>
    {
        public FileTemplateMap()
        {
            Table("FILE_TEMPLATE");
#if POSTGRE
            Map(f => f.Xml, "XML").CustomSqlType("TEXT");
#else
            Map(f => f.Xml, "XML").CustomSqlType("NCLOB");
#endif
        }
    }
```

Now I have to do different builds for oracle and postgresql with defining conditional compilation symbols (for postgresql). And application that build with POSTGRE compilation symbol doesn't work with oracle.

Are there other ways to do this without using conditional compilation symbols? I want to have one build, that works with both databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a little differently.
Here is an article about my solution: http://beamyplum.blogspot.ru/2013/08/nhibernate.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this

```
public static class CustomSqlTypeHelpers
{
    static readonly string _ClobSqlType;

    static CustomSqlTypeHelpers()
    {
        // Checks to validate config file setting ommitted
        _ClobSqlType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClobSqlType"];
    }

    public static PropertyPart LargeTextColumn(this PropertyPart pp)
    {
        return pp.CustomSqlType(_ClobSqlType);
    }
}

public FileTemplateMap()
{
    Table("FILE_TEMPLATE");
    Map(f => f.Xml, "XML").LargeTextColumn()
}
```